# TreeMap<String ,ArrayList<String>> specific printing/sorting

Tags: java, sorting, printing, treemap

I have a query that I would like your opinion .
I have stored in an ArrayList() called trips which includes register flightNo(String) , country(String) , people(int) and from the other in a HashMap(float,String) called distances where the String is the country and the float is the distance.I want to compare the two collections(by checking the destination) and if is the same have an output where I get the flightNo ,destination,distance , people and another attribute(calculated from the distance and the passengers).

I have an input like ArrayList(Trips) in which the same flightNo can  go to different countries

```
  No   Country People
 AB12  France   100
 CD23   UK      120
 AB12  Italy    80
 FR45  Italy    45
 SE56  Sweden   120 
 FR34  Norway   125
 CD23  Poland   200
 NM89  Romania  100
 KL78  Bulgaria 125
```

The other input is like HashMap(float , String) in which float is the distance and the String is the country.It looks like this:

```
Country   Distance
France   900.45 miles
UK       1200.32 miles
Italy    1010.34 miles
Sweden   1500.89 miles 
Norway   140.12 miles
Poland   700.98 miles
Romania  600.21 miles   
Bulgaria 1035.23 miles
```

So I want to check according to the destination and get an output like that

```
  No   Country People   Distance       fuelConsumption(distance * people)
 CD23   UK      120  1200.32 miles       1000 (i.e)
 AB12  Italy    80   1010.34 miles       800
 FR45  Italy    45   1010.34 miles       500 
 SE56  Sweden   120  1500.89 miles       340 
 FR34  Norway   125  140.12 miles        310
 CD23  Poland   200  700.98 miles        250 
 NM89  Romania  100  600.21 miles        100 
 KL78  Bulgaria 125  1035.23 miles        90
```

So I have reached in the spot where I have got all these information stored in a TreeMap (String ,ArrayList) called details where I have as a key the countries and have put all the info I want in the values of this TreeMap as an ArrayList of Strings.

I don't know how to have an output in a nice format and secondly get/print the first three and the last three destinations regarding the fuel Consumption.

This is the code I have written and returns me the TreeMap details where I get the values and want to print somehow.

```
public Map<String, TreeSet<String>> getDetails()

{
    for (Float distance : destinations.keySet())

    {

        String destinations = destinations.get(distance);

        for (Journeys j : journeys) {
            String places = j.getDestination();

            if (destinations.equals(places)) {

               *//destinationsList is a TreeSet<String>*
                destinationsList = details.get(destinations);

                if (destinationsList == null) {
                    destinationsList = new TreeSet<String>();
                }

                destinationsList.add((j.getFlight() + "        "
                        + j.getCountry() + "      " + distance
                        + "miles" + "       " + j.getPeople()
                        + "         " + j.getFuelConsumption(distance))
                        + "\n");

                details.put(destinations, destinationsList);

            }

        }

    }

    return details;
}
```

in the destinationsList.add I have tried to give a nice format when  I was entering the values but no luck.And also I don't know if I have to store them with another way to get a I explained the first and last three entries regarding the fuelConsumption.Sorted by fuel instead of sorting now according to the countries they way I have done it.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you do not need a TreeMap or TreeSet. Try following:

1. join the information of trips and distances (I think this is your Journey Object) and put every Journey into an ArrayList **journeys**
2. compute the fuel consumption on every Journey object (should be a field of Journey)
3. sort (Collections.sort) **journeys**  by fuel consumption
4. select the first/last three entries from **journeys** and put them in another ArrayList **selectedJourneys**
5. Implement a toString-Method of Journey (you could use tabs to get a table-like representation)
6. print selectedJourneys (each Journey in one Line)

Using Java 8 (Streaming-API) could help. Is this a possible approach to your problem, or did you need a problem for some of the numbered Steps?